# search box not getting positioned in css3

Tags: html, css

```css
input[type=text] {
  margin-left: 63%;
  margin-top: -100%;
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
  <form>
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
    </form>
```

even after puttin margin-top -100% the search box is not going up. it stopped going up after -10%. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: try changing position to relative , and try adjusting top margin with a px value instead of percent value

Comment: yes i tried but the search box moves till value -10px after this no matter how much i increase it like -100px it just doesn't go up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "position:relative" and "top:-100px". It will move your search box to move up. You can increase the 'top' value as you need.

```
input[type=text] {
margin-left: 63%;
width: 130px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: black;
background-image: url('searchicon.png');

background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
-webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
position: relative;
top: -100px;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
width: 150px;
}
```